# Android AsyncHttpResponseHandler response headers not working

Tags: loopj

I'm using loopj 1.4.3 and the following method inside AsyncHttpResponseHandler doesn't work:

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int k, Header[] headers,String response) {
            onSuccess(k, response);
        }
```

The onSuccess works without response header part. When I add the 'Header[] headers' as argument, the following error will occur;'Header cannot be resolved to a type'.

Thank you for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I made a new library from the latest loopj classes. I guess that onSuccess method wasn't available in the 1.4.3 library.